# When using flask-swagger, response body model does not show and creates 404 error

Tags: flask, swagger, flask-restful

I'm setting up flask-swagger to a project, and this project is made using flask-restful. It shows request body modeling and example, but does not shows response body modeling and example, only displaying description. I found that it was creating 404 error on swagger-ui generated page. this is an example of error message.

```
{
  "messages": [
    "attribute paths.'/users'(get).200.application/json is unexpected"
  ],
  "schemaValidationMessages": [
    {
      "level": "error",
      "domain": "validation",
      "keyword": "additionalProperties",
      "message": "object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"description\"]",
      "schema": {
        "loadingURI": "#",
        "pointer": ""
      },
      "instance": {
        "pointer": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want displaying response body modeling and example. I added yaml file below.

```
class User(Resource)
def get(self):
    """
    get users
    ---
    tags:
      - users
    parameters:
     -in: body
      required:
        -  user_id
      schema:
        properties:
          user_id:
            type: string
            description: user id
     responses:
       200:
         description: ok
         content:
           application/json
             schema:
               type: object
               properties:
                 user_name:
                   type: string
                   description: user name
     """
     example code 
     return jsonify(user_name=username)
```

Comment: You are mixing `swagger: '2.0'` and `openapi: 3.0.0` syntax. What version of the syntax do you need to use?

Comment: @Helen `swagger : 2.0` is what I need